# another post a page problem

Tags: pagination

I have a difficult post a page problem.
I have this code :

```
function wpse31701_4filter_query() { 
global $wp_query; 
// Check year and month 
$wp_query->set('orderby', 'date'); $wp_query->set('order', 'ASC'); 
if ( $wp_query->get( 'year' ) == 2005 and $wp_query->get( 'monthnum' ) == 9 ) 
    // Check page number to apply offset 
    if ( $wp_query->get( 'paged') == 2 ) $wp_query->set( 'offset', 1 ); 
    else 
     if ( $wp_query->get( 'paged') == 3 ) $wp_query->set( 'offset', 2 ); 
    else
      if ( $wp_query->get( 'paged') == 4 ) $wp_query->set( 'offset', 3 ); 
    else
    if ( $wp_query->get( 'paged') < 8  )  
       $wp_query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1);
```

}

It's don't work because I get a 500 error.
The problem I have it that on the first 8 pages only 1 article is displayed. On the rest the normal number of articles is displayed.

Who can help me find out how I get this working.

Roelof

Comment: Please use brackets and intend your code to make it readable.

Comment: Could you pls copy/paste the code from the other answer and update/edit yours? How shall later readers who search for the same solution read & understand your code? I'm close to closing this post as "too localized".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***"The problem I have it that on the first 8 pages only 1 article is displayed."***

That would be due to this line of code:

```
if ( $wp_query->get( 'paged') < 8  )  {
  $wp_query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1);
}
```

See here for more info: [codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)

## EDIT:

Try adding brackets as mentioned by @kaiser... Here's your original code you posted in pastebin with brackets/indentions added where I *think* they're supposed to go...

```
function wpse31701_filter_query() {
  global $wp_query;
  // Check year and month
  $wp_query->set('orderby', 'date'); $wp_query->set('order', 'ASC');
  if ( $wp_query->get( 'year' ) == 2005 and $wp_query->get( 'monthnum' ) == 4 ) {
    // Check page number to apply offset
    if ( $wp_query->get( 'paged') == 2 ) {
      $wp_query->set( 'offset', 1 );
    }
    else {
      if ( $wp_query->get( 'paged') == 3 ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'offset', 4 );
      }
      else {
        $wp_query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse31701_filter_query' );
```

Your first "if" statement had no brackets around what it was supposed to evaluate. If you code conditionals without brackets, then it's only going to evaluate the first line following it. If there's more than one line in the evaluation, you need to either use brackets or colons.

Now, I'm not sure if this is going to fix your problem... but it's at least a very good idea to properly format the code first before trying to debug any "problems", as the formatting very well may be one of, if not "the" problem.

Comment: I know it;s that line when I change it back to this : [link] (http://pastebin.com/Rrp3RwhM) then it works perfectly but only on page1 where I need it on page 2 and so on

Comment: I see I can do the job with wp-query but I hope someone has a example how I then check which month is displayed

Comment: See the edits above

Comment: Hello, using brackets and change it to this `if ( $wp_query->get( 'paged') == 2 ) {$wp_query->set( 'offset', 1 );  $wp_query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1); }`
did the job

Answer (score 0):

First: The query var is named "`page`", not paged. Second: it is only set when you are on page > 1. Else it simply is empty.

Comment: I see I can do the job with wp-query but I hope someone has a example how I then check which month is displayed